# Recover the original HTML or DOM before modification from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, events

A legacy website uses JavasSript to remove certain elements when not compatible with the current browser.  Something like:

```
if (!navigator.javaEnabled())
  document.getElementById('greenscreen').innerHTML = '<p>Not Supported on this browser';
```

Is there a simple way to either recover the original HTML / DOM (at least of the deleted elements), or to ensure our script runs before this script, or to otherwise find out what was in `#greenscreen`? We can't modify the existing JavaScript, but need to somehow add new JavaScript to parse the `#greenscreen` HTML and get the info.

Comment: No, the original HTML isn't saved anywhere automatically. You'd need code that runs before it, then it can save the `innerHTML` to a variable.

Comment: @Barmar How can I ensure my code runs before it? Especially given modern code using `async` automatically.

Comment: In the HTML, add an inline `<script>window.oldGreen = document.getElementById('greenscreen').innerHTML;</script>` before the legacy script loader.  BTW, please include the HTML code

Comment: @Barmar The original **must** be available at least to the browser, because view-source shows the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your goal is to parse some HTML, here's an approach that works if you don't rely on *any* modifications done to the DOM by any JS run by this webpage: Just do a HTTP request using the URL of the page (`document.location.href`). Ex. with the Fetch API: `await (await fetch(document.location.href)).text()`.

If you want to use DOM methods on it, then turn it into a document:

```js
(async function() {
  const html = await fetch(document.location.href)).text();
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
  doc.getElementById("greenscreen");
  // TODO
})();
```